# Implicit parameters of anonymous functions in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm a bit stuck with implicit parameters of anonymous functions. Hope somebody'll point me the right direction. Here is what I have. Two files: `Main.scala` and `Foo.scala`:

```
// Foo.scala
trait Fun[-A, +B] extends (A => B)

trait ImplicitString[+B] {
  def withString(block: String => B)(implicit s: String): B = block(s)
}

object FooFun extends Fun[String, String] with ImplicitString[String] {
  def apply(x: String): String = withString { implicit s =>
    x + s
  }
}
```

And

```
// Main.scala
object Main extends App {
  implicit val s = "it works!"
  println(FooFun("Test:"))
}
```

I'm expecting to see `Test: it works!` printed. But I got a compilation error:

```
$ scalac Main.scala Service.scala
Service.scala:8: error: could not find implicit value for parameter s: String
  def apply(x: String): String = withString { implicit s =>
                                        ^
one error found
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**:

Looks like I should have imported my implicit val like this:

```
// Foo.scala
import Main._
...
```

This works fine.

Comment: `(A => B)` is nothing but `Function[-A, +B]`, so your `trait Fun` really isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `s` directly inside function, there's no point of marking it as implicit.

You can fix this in this way,

```
object FooFun extends Fun[String, String] with ImplicitString[String] {
  def apply(x: String)(implicit s1:String): String = withString { s =>
    x + s
  }
}
```

The problem is, `implicit val s` is not visible to the apply method body of `FooFun`.

Comment: I tried this. This can't be compiled since `FooFun` is no longer implements `Fun` trait: there is no `apply: String => String` function in `FooFun`. There is just: `apply: String => (String => String)`.

Comment: Folks, please, try to compile it before +1ing.